# In general, are programs that store passwords safe?

Tags: password-management

The reason I was curious is because it provides a feature that saves the SSH password and allows me to not have to enter the password the next time I connect through VLC. If someone else gets access to my physical device (computer, smartphone, etc.), can they get these passwords?

In my opinion, since 'plain text' must be entered to ultimately connect to SSH, a hacker will be able to obtain this password. (Because it is stored somewhere as 'plain text', or the encrypted text must be instantly decrypted and entered into the SSH connection logic through memory)

Additionally, I think that the 'Save Password' function provided by browsers (Edge, Chrome, FireFox) will be enough to obtain passwords if a hacker gets the device. Is this right?

Comment: It's always security vs convenience.  You'd have to decide whether one outweighs the other, but given the same amount of complexity any saved password (on the computer, written on a slip of paper, etc..) is less secure than memorizing it.  Synching saved passwords on the "cloud" is also less secure than isolating them (and their encryption keys, if used) to a single device.  If stored locally encryption/decryption should be based on a hardware-read value and/or a remembered master password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, if an attacker compromises your device, then he/she would be able to gain access to all of your saved passwords, if your passwords are saved in plaintext.

Even if you use a password manager (or similar program) that encrypts your passwords before storing them using a key derived from a master password that you memorize - an attacker that has compromised your device could gain access to these passwords by planting a key logger or memory dump program on your device, to capture the master password when you enter it.

And, even if you use no method at all to store your passwords, and you simply memorize your passwords and enter them when needed - an attacker that has compromised your device could gain access to these passwords when you enter them, using a key logger or memory dump program.

So, the point is - **once the attacker has compromised your device, it's game over**.

So, you don't have much to loose by using a password manager (or similar program that stores passwords).  But, there is much to be gained by using such a program, as this enables you to use individual passwords that have much more entropy than you could possibly have with memorized passwords.

Comment: there's still theft of the device...  slightly different in that a keylogger is of no use to the thief unless they return the device back to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Password managers usually encrypt their stored passwords with a key derived (at least partially) from the password you use to unlock them.  That may be a separate password for a standalone password manager or it may be your OS account password for something like your browser's password store or an OS keychain.

Without that password an attacker will be unable to derive the key to decrypt your stored passwords, even with physical access to the system.

---

This is, of course, true only for well-designed password managers.  It's fully possible that a poorly-designed piece of software could store your password unencrypted in a text file on disk.